# Can Vert.x Event Bus be integrated in JBoss/WildFly?

Tags: java, servlets, websocket, jboss, vert.x

### Description of the current setup

I have a JBoss Application Server where the '.ear' is deployed. The Application is using Spring for dependency injection.It currently use Spring 3.0. There is a **DispatcherServlet** declared in the **web.xml** used for API-Spring Integration and other servlets for other purposes.

### The problem

I have to integrate a real-time functionality which require bidirectional communication between server and client. I know that can be done with websockets under the hood but I wonder if the **vert.x event bus** can be used as a messaging system between the browser and the server. **Vert.x** is a web server as far I know (maybe is more that that) and I'm not sure if the event-bus module can be used JBoss Servlet context.

### Question

Is there a way to integrate Vert.x Event Bus using websockets under the hood in JBoss/WildFly App Server?

### My Research

- I didn't found any documentation/code snippets from vert.x that can answer my question (maybe I'm missing something)

Answer (score 0):

Vert.x Event-Bus communicates with browser-client via [the bridge](https://vertx.io/docs/vertx-tcp-eventbus-bridge/java/) which is based on SockJS which in turn uses WebSockets under the hood (along with some fallback protocols).

If you need only this functionality, it doesn't really makes sense to include Vert.x in the mix and Spring's Websocket support should be enough.

Comment: Understood, but my main question is if it's possible the integration?

Comment: yes, why not? I integrated vertx into a Grails (springboot++) application as a singleton service. Fairly straight-forward